# error in your SQL syntax;ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Trying the below commands on `MySQL 5.6` but getting syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO device 
            ( uid, name, type, os, device_active, 
              screen_resolution, network_type,status) 
    VALUES ('1110b','XIAOMI','Android','Android 10',
            false,'2340*1080','WIFI',1),
           ('A2QD1','HUAWEI','Android','Android 7.0',
            true,'1920*1080','WIFI',1) As new 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE device_active = VALUES(new.device_active);
```

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'As new ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE device_active = VALUES(new.device_active)'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried to resolve that error?

Comment: Is this a Trigger? It does not look like one! So `new.` is not available to you

Comment: (1) Alias is not applicable for row data. `As new` is wrong and must be removed. (2) VALUES() functoin is applied to the columns of destination table only, `new.` is wrong and must be removed.

Comment: @Akina same error with VALUES(device_active)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=74a6b94ffe12973960277a6577feeb24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NEW. values are only available in triggers VALUES(device_active) should be enough.

Comment: Still same error

Comment: Moreover, NEW in the trigger is NOT a table.